# GCM with queues

Tags: c++, file-io, crypto++

I'm looking to encrypt a file scattered with (custom) start/end markers using AES/GCM, such that the output file contains plain text and encrypted sections as needed.  Crypto++ library seems to be a good candidate.  I can think of various ways to do it, but I am hazy on the most appropriate.

My shot in the dark:

1. Setup a FileSource/Sink pipeline with no pumping
2. Loop

   - Write/put plain data to sink/ofstream
   - Place MessageEnd() after start and before end markers
   - Pump message

I'm not sure if it makes sense, or exactly how for that matter, to make use of IsolatedInitiliaze with ValueNames()?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right. You won't need to call `MessageEnd`, except when everything is done. The library won't understand your notion of a message unless you layer the logic on-top of Crypto++.

Comment: @jww: Thanks.  In my case I ended up not having to use `MessageEnd` since I used a stream filter to manually `Put2` where needed.  It would be handy if there were a `Name` value for a line prefix, but I found a work around.

Comment: *"It would be handy if there were a Name value for a line prefix"* - Bring it up on the [Crypto++ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cryptopp-users) (its just a Google Group). If the community agrees, I would be happy to check it in.

Comment: Appears `MessageEnd` is required to pad the last block of each crypted section?  In this case I don't have the option to call `MessageEnd` only at the end of the input file - as advised [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/0k3GbjixrN8) - since there are unencrypted sections.  Any advice on how to use `AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher` on a file with multiple messages, or any better strategy?